# Load more in CloudKit with swift

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I have 2 functions loadData and loadMore as below:

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class HireView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    let myData = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
    let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.loadData()    
    }

    func loadData(){
        var result = [CKRecord]()
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Hire", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "postDate", ascending: false)]
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.resultsLimit = 100
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                result.append(record)
                hireItems = result
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
            if error != nil {

            } else {
                if result.isEmpty == true {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        hireItems = result
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
    myData.add(operation)
    }

    func loadMore(){
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Hire", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "postDate", ascending: false)]
        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.resultsLimit = hireItems.count + 100
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) in
            if (record["postDate"] as! Date) < (hireItems[hireItems.count - 1]["postDate"] as! Date) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    hireItems.append(record)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) in
            if error != nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {                            
                }
            } else {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        myData.add(operation)
    }
}
```

My question is:

Is `loadMore()` function the best? 
Is there any way to make `loadMore()` better?

Answer (score 0):

A better aproach could be use the [CKQueryCursor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckquerycursor) returned in the `queryCompletionBlock` of CKQueryOperation.

If this cursor is not `nil` then you have more records waiting to be fetched. To continue *fetching* you should use the [init(cursor: CKQueryCursor)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckqueryoperation/1515033-init) initializer.

> Use this method to initialize a query operation that retrieves the
>   next batch of results from a previous search.